# Checking queue.empty() yields puzzling behavior

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using multiple threads to pull data from multiple sensors with different acquisition rates. I have a camera collecting at 30Hz, and a multi-axis IMU collecting at 200Hz. Inside the methods that collect the data, I do some base-line processing and shove the data in a queue to be used by the main code.

I start my main with the following below. camq, inerq, and plotq are all Queue.Queue() objects. cammer, inertial, and plotter are all methods with infinite loops collecting data and pushing it into the queues.

```
t1 = Thread(target=cammer, args = (camq,))
t2 = Thread(target = inertial, args = (inerq,))
t3 = Thread(target = plotter, args = (plotq,))
t1.setDaemon(True)
t2.setDaemon(True)
t3.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

The key values for my application are the IMU values. Thus, In an infinite loop in my main code the pacing item is the queue reading those values. my issue is I don't want to wait for the camera queue to populate before the code continues to step through. Therefore, I've done the following in the main code:

```
while True:
    result = inerq.get() #Get the inertial data as it comes

    #Many lines of inertial processing code

    if not camq.empty(): #Check if the camera queue is empty
        if camq.get_nowait() >297 and camq.get_nowait() <303: #If it isn't empty poll it to see if it meets the criteria.

            #Many lines of kalman filtering
```

I want to use the queue.get_nowait() so I'm not sitting around waiting for my camera data, which comes much slower than the IMU data. When I do this, I get queue.empty, so I handle that with the queue.empty() query above.

When I do this, I get the error "main thread is not in the main loop". It's worth noting, if I simply do this:

```
if camq.get() >297 and camq.get() <303: #Poll the camera data

            #Many lines of kalman filtering
```

The code runs perfectly, but much slower as it's awaiting the camera data every loop.

Could someone provide me a strategy or insight that will allow me to not "wait" for the camera queue?

Comment: Why are you doing `camq.get_nowait()` *twice*?

Comment: Yeah, that's dumb, it's polling it twice.